# No results on view after granting select for that specific user - Default User sees results

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

I want to **grant another user privileges on a view** I have created with the default user.

With the default user I am able to get a result of over `7000 rows`.

With the other user I cannot get any rows as a result.

- I have granted the other user select privileges on the view.
- I granted select privileges on every sub table or sub view for that
  user.
- I compared permissions of other views that can be seen with the other
  user for permissions and could not find any difference.

There is no error message but the info that `0 rows` have been selected.

Comment: are you getting records when you execute the query of the view from another user? You must check for the Policy on the tables also.

Comment: I tried running the query on the different user and still got no result rows. every sub table has the required permissions as well...

Comment: are you adding the schema name ? @C.Henke

Comment: yes i am. if i wouldn't it would return an error already @Moudiz 
selecting other tables that have granted privileges can be done without problems

Comment: *"sub view"* - this view is a join or tables and other views? If so I'd focus the search of those views: it's possible they have something in the WHERE clause which filters data based on user. Also check for user-defined functions declared with Invoker Rights.

Comment: @APC If you post this as answer i would mark this as correct, thank you !

Comment: It was just a lucky guess on my part. Glad if it helped you solve the problem. I suggest you post (and accept) an answer explaining your solution..

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be found in a sub-sub-sub-view that had a where clause. This where clause stated, that the executing user needed to have specific company permissions, granted in the onlying application. Once granted the view returned results.

Thanks to @APC for the suggestion.